# If all points lie on regression line, how is coefficient of correlation affected?

Tags: correlation, linear-regression

If all points lie on a regression line, what does that mean for the coefficient of correlation? Am I correct to say the coefficient of correlation is either -1, 0 or 1?

Comment: This is only right if the regression line has a slope of 0,1 or -1.

Comment: Presuming the OP means $\varrho$ he's right.

Comment: @callculus Could you provide your comment as the answer, please?